# RecordWildCards for non record functions

Tags: haskell

Lets consider following record datatype `D` and function `bar`:

```hs
data D
  = D
    { foo :: Int
    }

bar :: D -> Int
```

**Is it somehow possible** (for example by language extension like: `RecordWildCards`) **to simplify usage of `bar` like `foo` is?**

```hs
test :: D -> IO ()
test D{..} = do
  print foo -- fine
  print bar -- not fine
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen here?  I think you have it right: `print foo` is fine (with `RecordWildCards`), but `print bar` is definitely not fine.

Comment: Do you propose that the compiler should bind names of all possible functions that can accept `D` as parameter?

Comment: @DDub yes, exactly

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it might help, is there such extension? or any serious drawbacks?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such extension currently.

`RecordWildCards` doesn’t introduce *calls* to the record selector functions; it’s a syntactic sugar for *patterns* that’s just shorthand for listing the fields out explicitly or with `NamedFieldPuns`. For instance, with a datatype like this:

```
data Example = Example
  { exThis :: This
  , exThat :: That
  , exThese :: These
  , exThose :: Those
  }
```

A function using `RecordWildCards`…

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
f Example{..} = g exThis exThat exThese exThose
```

…is syntactic sugar for either of these.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
f Example { exThis, exThat, exThese, exThose }
  = g exThis exThat exThese exThose
```

```
f Example
  { exThis = exThis
  , exThat = exThat
  , exThese = exThese
  , exThose = exThose
  }
  = g exThis exThat exThese exThose
```

Which is also equivalent to this, assuming `a`…`d` are fresh (unused) variable names.

```
f Example
  { exThis = a
  , exThat = b
  , exThese = c
  , exThose = d
  }
  = g a b c d
```

It’s *not* equivalent to this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
f x@Example
  = g (exThis x) (exThat x) (exThese x) (exThose x)
```

Note that this desugaring would also be *less strict* (more lazy) in some cases than the real desugaring.

When a function is *monomorphic*, like `bar`, your extension would work fine, and you could even implement a GHC extension to do so if you wanted. Note, however, that it would be ambiguous in many cases, that is, any time you had two or more record wildcards in scope, and a polymorphic function that could accept any of them.